# Pandas DataFrame - Normalisation

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns:  doc_id, text

I have tokenised my text but I want to create a new row for each doc_id, token.

What is the most efficient way for me to do this?

As-is:

```
doc_id    text
1         "cat mat home"
2         "dog mat table"
```

To-be:

```
doc_id    text
1         cat
1         mat
1         home
2         dog
2         mat
2         table
```

Comment: Would you like show us some sample data ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thanks for the reply - I have added an example of sample as-is and to-be states